# Get authorization code from refreshtoken

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-api, dotnetopenauth

I am using dotnetopenauth and working with google api. My problem is to get authorization code from my saved refresh token. If i can get that code then i can get accesstoken. i want to get that code not accesstoken directly. I was unable to find any method or url of end point which can return me authorization code from my refresh token. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the OAuth 2 flow confused. Authorization codes do not come from refresh tokens. It's the other way around: you get refresh tokens in exchange for a one-time-use of your authorization code. Access tokens are obtained in any of three ways

1. In exchange for a refresh token.
2. In the initial exchange for the authorization code that returns both a refresh token and an access token.
3. OR, if you're using the implicit grant type instead of the authorization code flow, you get the access token in the url #fragment in response to the user's authorization redirect, but this only applies to JavaScript executing on the browser since fragments are not sent to web servers.